# PHP How to get a Variable to work in a array loop?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, row

This is what i have at th moment.

```
    <?php 
    $name = ($row1[2]); 
    if($row1[45] == 1){
            echo("<td class='nameSelect'>$name</td>");
        }
        else{
            echo("<td>$name</td>");
        } 
    ?>
```

But i want the $row1[2] to change to $row2[2], $row3[2] and so on with a loop.

```
    <?php 
    $r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    for ($s = 0; $s < $r[4]; ++$s){

        $name = ($row1[2]); //Here are my problem
        if($row1[45] == 1){
                echo("<td class='nameSelect' colspan='6'>$name</td>");
            }
            else{
                echo("<td colspan='6'>$name</td>");
            } 
    }; 
    ?>
```

How do i get the $row1[2] to work with $s to become something like ($row $s [2])
Is it possible? Or do i have to re-think my setup?

Comment: where does `$row` come from? I don't see it declared anywhere...

Comment: It would be easier if you could change it to `$row[1][2]`, so then you can do `$row[$s][2]`. Given your current format, I believe what you are looking for in the current format is `${'row'.$s}[2]`

Comment: I think you clearly need to rethink your setup. No offense, but since you asked: this looks like garbage

Comment: @giorgio sry i thought it was obvious it came from an $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

Comment: @AndreschSerj ty for your valuable input. Pleas explain to me why and how you think it would look.

Comment: If you use `$row1 = mysqli_fetch...` and `$row2 = mysql_fetch ...`, why don't you just use `$row[] = mysqli_fetch...` and then access them using the given key i.e. `$row[0]`? I actually do not understand why you would write such code. You assign a result row to `$r`, then you go into a for loop and work with the fields from this and other rows. This all seems very dirty. A row havin 45 fields? Why not name those results and fields? Who would understand such code later on? But who am i to judge. Anyway, Rsauxil answered your question. Please accept his answer and let us all get on ;-)

Comment: @AndreschSerj ty for your input, every answer i get i learn more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<?php
for ($s = 0; $s < $r[4]; ++$s)
{
    $name = ${"row".$s}[2]; //Here is my problem
    if (${"row".$s}[45] == 1)
    {
        echo "<td class='nameSelect' colspan='6'>$name</td>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<td colspan='6'>$name</td>";
    } 
}
?>
```

For more information check [Variable variables on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: TY verry much @Rsauxil

Answer (score 1):

```
$temp = 'row1[2]'; // you can vari 1,2 with variable 

$another_row = $$temp;
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `while` for fetching results:

```
<?php 
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
   $name = $row1[ 2 ]; 
   if( $row1[45] == 1 ) {
     echo "<td class='nameSelect'>".$name."</td>";
   } else {
     echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>");
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: i didn't downvote but to be honest, without any explaination this answer does not really solve his/her problem right? Surely, one might think this code is the product of someone trying the wrong thing. But we don't know that. Maybe this is some weird scenario where this for loop is needed exactly like this and we don't know what happens later on and so on and so on ... so i guess that's why someone downvoted.

Comment: I get what you are saying. Updating the same. My idea was to infer that the OP is not using a `while` loop to go through the whole resultset, updating my post.